Not sure if lsblk showing correct partitions after restoring RAID1
One of my disk (nvme0n1) fails, so it was replaced. Now lsblk shows
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:5    0   511M  0 part
├─nvme0n1p2 259:6    0 475.9G  0 part
│ └─md2       9:2    0 475.8G  0 raid1 /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:7    0   512M  0 part
nvme1n1     259:1    0 476.9G  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1 259:2    0   511M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme1n1p2 259:3    0 475.9G  0 part
│ └─md2       9:2    0 475.8G  0 raid1 /
└─nvme1n1p3 259:4    0   512M  0 part  [SWAP]

But I'm afraid that nvme0n1p3 is not mounted as SWAP as nvme1n1p3, and the same situation is with nvme0n1p1.
What I do after replacing disk is:
sgdisk --backup=nvme1n1.sgdisk /dev/nvme1n1
sgdisk --load-backup=nvme1n1.sgdisk /dev/nvme0n1
sgdisk -G /dev/nvme0n1
mdadm --manage /dev/md2 --add /dev/nvme0n1p2

Is that correct configuration? If nvme1n1 will fail, system will boot correctly?
